# Docker private registry issue

Tags: proxy, docker, ubuntu-14.04, docker-registry

I run private registry on **UBUNTU 14.04**:

> docker run -d -p 5000:5000 registry

The proces appeard on my docker proces list. I wrote command : **curl *my-external-ip*** and I got this:

> "\"docker-registry server\""

**THE PROBLEM IS** that
when I try to push image on localhost it works fine, but after I want to push to external ip (It must be available for for more people) I got this:

> The push refers to a repository [MY-EXTERNAL-IP:5000/hello] (len: 1)
>   unable to ping registry endpoint https://MY-EXTERNAL-IP:5000/v0/
>   v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://MY-EXTERNAL-IP:5000/v2/: EOF
>    v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get ht*ps://MY-EXTERNAL-IP:5000/v1/_ping: EOF

I am using proxy at my company, but I added export **http_proxy, https_proxy, ftp_proxy** to my docker file and **--insecure-registry**.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that your docker daemon can't access docker registry(your-external-ip) through `https` protocol(usually it uses 443 port). 
Maybe you can check it first.

But with insecure mode, the network occured on http protocol. So you can tell you docker daemon to trust insecure-registry.

Try to run docker daemon with `--insecure-registry="YOUR_EXTERNAL_IP"`

Comment: If you don't want to restart your docker service you can use
`docker pull --allow-insecure-ssl` which do same thing, but on the client

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Docker daemon still doesn't understand that registry on your `$EXTERNAL_IP` should be accessed over HTTP rather than HTTPS. You need to be sure that daemon runs with the `--insecure-registry $EXTERNAL_IP` option:

```
ps aux | grep docker
```

If you'll not be able to find it there, you probably made a mistake in your `DOCKER_OPTIONS`.